# Cannot access OpenShift console using Chrome

Tags: networking, openshift-origin

I'm really new to OpenShift and system administration.

I installed OpenShift on a OVH VPS server, following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aqXSbDZggK4)

Now, I want to access the OpenShift Console, which should be accessible from `https://console.example.com:8443/`

```
oc login -u THELOGIN -p THEPASSWORD https://console.example.com:8443/
Login successful.
```

When I access the address `https://console.example.com:8443/` on Google Chrome, it shows the console for a few seconds, and then displays this message : DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

How can I allow Google Chrome to access this web page ?

Comment: You need to make sure that `console.example.com` resolves, hence you need to put some `A` or `AAAA`  records in your zonefile for the `console` label.

Comment: Thank you, I bought a domain name and was able to put an A record for the console label. It worked ! I will had details in my post.

Could you add your message as an answer ?